# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource using Spring4

Tags: html, spring-mvc

Am using Spring4. I have added a class as below as described in one of the solutions. But still the problem persists. Am not using Web.xml file instead am using **WebApplicationInitializer**. Could anyone suggest me whats going wrong. Am also using **html5**

@Component

public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

public void destroy() {}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right i found the answer: Apart from using a Filter and Configuring it in **WebApplicationInitializer**. One need to create an **HandlerInterceptorAdapter**. Code below. This solved my problem.

public class CronsInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        return true;
```

}